# Is there any tool that I can use to monitor memory usage of each process on Linux easily?

Tags: linux, memory-usage, top

This issue is not the same as the question on [how to see the memory usage of a Linux process](https://serverfault.com/questions/264843/how-can-i-see-the-memory-usage-of-a-linux-process).

Also, the `top` command doesn't give the exact memory used, but just what percentage one process uses, so is there any powerful tool which I can use to monitor memory usage of each process on Linux easily?

Comment: Virtual memory? Physical memory? Resident set? It would help a lot to know what you're actually trying to do so that we could tell you the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Ummmm, how about `top`?

The `VIRT`, `RES`, and `SHR` columns (which are present by default in every version of top I've used) list memory consumed (in kb), which is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I use htop.

[image: htop image]

Extra characters.....

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like `top` for whatever reason, you can also monitor the memory usage of running process (and just about anything else) with `Cacti`, which would give you a nice visual output, too.

In fact, someone over at the Cacti forums wrote up a script for this very thing...  the [memory usage of your running processes on one graph](http://forums.cacti.net/about31990.html).  It's for Windows, but this is pretty easy (easier, even) to do in Linux with Cacti, too.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

Areas of memory assigned for a process may be read-only, copy-on-write or writeable. Only in the case of writeable (non-shared) memory is it assigned directly to the process. Read-only and COW pages cannot easily be counted only once where it has multiple references (since each process sees the physical pages at different addresses).

[ps_mem.py](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py) does a better job than ps / top et al - but it's still a long way from being an accurate measure of what's really going on with memory - particularly on a machine raunning lots of servers.